# How can I summon the touch keyboard from a Windows 7 tablet, through winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, touch, tablet

Basically I just need to be able to summon the keyboard whenever a user touches a text box in my application, instead of them having to go to the taskbar and actually request that the keyboard is summoned.

Does anybody have any idea how to do this? Whether there is a specific touch API I can touch into? My application is currently written in winforms and c#.

Many thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.Start(@"C:\windows\system32\osk.exe");